# cannot remove the source maps from react project

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I want to disable the source maps so that my code will not appear in the deployment link source. As you will see on the screenshot I changed the `build` and I created `.env` file but still it does not work and the code is still visible. Also the `.env` file won't be committed and it says `Untracked Files`.
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Delete your build folder entirely, and then try to run the build again. Are the source maps still there?

Comment: I did that and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace the current `"build"` with `"build": "react-scripts build && rm build/static/js/*.map && rm build/static/css/*.map"` and it works. I twill remove the js and css from the sources.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing map files after a build.

```
"scripts": {    
    ...
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "postbuild": "rimraf build/**/*.map"
    ...
  }
```

Comment: badly, it makes a recursion call

Comment: try it adding postbuild